Does the magnetic field you find depend upon the size of the Amperian loop?
Will the value of magnetic field change if my amperian loops are changed if I am calculating it for the same current?
For example, if I take an infinitely long straight conductor, does magnetic field depend upon the size and length of the Amperian loop?

Have you tried writing the steps of an amperes law calculation for simple geometries like the infinite wire? We know empirically that the field depends on the distance from the wire so this shouldn't surprise you that your end result depends on the radius.

Let's word this much more carefully.  This is as much a wording issue as anything else.
An Amperean loop is the boundary of where we human decide to do the Ampere's law integral.  The current, the wire, and the produced magnetic field do not care how (and if) someone is doing some calculation!  If there is a magnetic field at some point, it is just there.  No lines or loops you draw with your pen or your imagination is going to affect it.
On the other hand, Ampere's law tells you to integrate the magnetic field along the loop.  If you draw you loop elsewhere, you integrate the field elsewhere.  You change your location, the field doesn't change.

But as the other answer says, won't doubling the radius of the loop cut the value of magnetic field in half? But that is obviously not right, since the magnetic field doesn't care about the loop? Is there a flaw in my logic?

@Neerada Nas I downvoted the other answer and wrote my own for a reason.

Yes, because Ampere's law determines the integral of the (component along the loop) of the magnetic field for a given current.  In your simple example, if you double the radius of a loop centered on and perpendicular to the wire, you cut the magnetic field in half to get the same integral.
Or, just turn the loop on its side so it doesn't contain the current.  Then the integral is zero.  Since I can consider another loop centered on the wire and perpendicular to it for which the integral cannot be zero, and just touches the sideways loop, then the field on different parts of the sidewise loop must change in order for the integral along it to be zero.

If the magnetic field indeed changes, how do we know which one to choose?

You don't.  The integral form of Ampere's law, like Gauss's law, only allows you to calculate the field at a general point in cases where you can rely on a symmetry, allowing you to pull the field out of the integral.   Of course, it always allows you to relate the line integral to the enclosed current.
